# WORD and PDF to text Web Service

Tags: web-services, pdf, text, ms-word

I'm looking to write (or use an existing) web service that takes an MS WORD and PDF file, extracts it's content and returns it as text.

Anyone knows of such a service or how to write one?

Answer (score 0):

For Word-to-text you can use [`antiword`](http://www.ghacks.net/2009/06/08/use-antiword-to-extract-text-from-doc-files/) and pass its output to the client.

For PDF, there's [PdfTk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) - its dump_data operation might be useful.

Comment: Thank you. Since I have a web application hosted on the web, I couldn't understand how I call these programs from a web application.

Comment: @Oded: Depends on the programming language, but each has a way to call external programs.